# How can I get only the object with my arrays returned from a function with a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I want the data in res passed to my notes variable. But it's returning a bigger nested object. Why is it happening? 
If I inspect in the console the value of cleanArrayOfNotes I get the object that I want, but once its assigned to notes it  becomes a quite bigger object. I understand it's part of the nature of the Promises, which at the moment I still trying to understand. Any help?

notes_service.js

```
var notesService = {notesObjectInService: [], newNote: null};


    notesService.getAll = function() {
        return $http.get('/notes.json').success(function(data){
            //console.log(data)
            angular.copy(data, notesService.notesObjectInService);
            //console.log(notesService)
        })
    };
```

navCtrl.js

```
var notes = notesService.getAll().then(function(res){

            var cleanArrayOfNotes = res.data;
            //navCtrl line12
            console.log(cleanArrayOfNotes);
            return cleanArrayOfNotes;
        });
        //navCtrl line16
        console.log(notes);
```

[image]

Comment: You assign the function to the notes variable, so it will be the `getAll()` which returns a `$http` promise. Your notes variable therefore is a promise, where your `cleanArrayOfNotes` is the resolved data

Comment: So how can I assign to a local variable only the resolved data?

Comment: assign it inside the promise.

Comment: `notes` is a promise for `cleanArrayOfNotes`. What else did you expect? Is there some code that works on `notes` that does not work?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

notes_service.js

```
app.factory ('NoteService', function($http) {
    return {
        getAll: function() {
            return $http.get('/notes.json').then(function(response) {
                  return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

navCtrl.js

```
    NotesService.getAll().then(function(res){

        $scope.cleanArrayOfNotes = res.data;

    });
```

Or, if you want to return the result rather than the promise, you can:

notes_service.js

```
app.factory ('NoteService', function($http) {
    var notes = [];
    var promise = $http.get('/notes.json').then(function(response) {
          angular.copy(response.data, notes);
          return notes;
    });    

    return {
        getAll: function() {
            return notes; 
        },
        promise: promise
    }
});
```

navCtrl.js

```
     // get array of notes
     scope.cleanArrayOfNotes = NotesService.getAll();

     // or use promise
     NoteService.promise.then(function(response) {
         scope.cleanArrayOfNotes = response.data;
     });
```

Comment: The last option has a race condition.

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: What if the notes in `getAll` did not load when the controller code is run? There is nothing telling it to wait for it, the way to make it avoid the race condition would be to `resolve:` in the router or some other mechanism.

Comment: Then, it would return the empty notes array. angular.copy is used to preserve the reference. This is a common pattern in Angular. It is not a race condition. NgResource is based on this pattern.